# MDX Query change column title

Tags: ssas, mdx, mdx-query

These are my first *mdx queries*. I would like to execute some queries from a *C#* application and convert the results to a *JSON* file or a tabular format.

So I need the columns titles, you can see in the picture in attachment the columns title is empty, how can I change them in the *mdx query* ?

```
SELECT { [Measures].[Nombre Inscrits] } ON COLUMNS, 
{ ([ZONE CLIENT].[ID ZONE].[ID ZONE].ALLMEMBERS * [DimDate].[Year].[Year].ALLMEMBERS)}
ON ROWS FROM [Loisirs cube]
```

[image: No title in columns]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The empty cells are empty because in the result space if a name is given to them, it will not make sense, I would suggest you handle it in your code. However for the sake of learning you can use the below query , and ignore the first two columns of the result

```
with member
[measures].[ID ZONE] as 
[ID ZONE].[ID ZONE].currentmember.name

[measures].[Year] as 
[DimDate].[Year].currentmember.name


SELECT 
{[measures].[ID ZONE],[measures].[Year], [Measures].[Nombre Inscrits] } ON COLUMNS,
{ ([ZONE CLIENT].[ID ZONE].[ID ZONE].ALLMEMBERS * [DimDate].[Year].[Year].ALLMEMBERS)}
ON ROWS FROM [Loisirs cube]
```

So here a sample on adventure works

```
SELECT 
{ [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] } ON COLUMNS, 
{ ([Product].[Category].[Category].ALLMEMBERS * [Date].[Calendar Year].[Calendar Year].ALLMEMBERS)}
ON ROWS 
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

Result
[image]

Now lets modify the query

```
with member 
 [Measures].[Category]
 as 
 [Product].[Category].currentmember.name

member [Measures].[Year]
as 
[Date].[Calendar Year].currentmember.name

SELECT 
{ [Measures].[Category], [Measures].[Year],[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] } ON COLUMNS, 
{ ([Product].[Category].[Category].ALLMEMBERS * [Date].[Calendar Year].[Calendar Year].ALLMEMBERS)}
ON ROWS 
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

Result

[image]

Comment: Thx @MoazRub, but your code does not work, may be because I have only [Nombre Inscrits] in Measures ?

Comment: @KiMaN did you copy the entire query? can you share what error is it giving

Comment: it's only "member" that was missing before [measures].[Year], and [ID ZONE] must be [ID ZONE].currentmember.name instead [ID ZONE].[ID ZONE].currentmember.name, Thanks !

Comment: can I exclude or remove the firsts columns, those which do not have title ? PS : Please edit your very good answer !

Comment: @KiMaN unfortunately you cannot remove them